# How to compensate for sinking / uneven floor in office

Tags: comfort, furniture, office, carpet

I rent an office on the 2nd floor of a 2 story building.  The carpet is the standard blue you find everywhere.  Certain sections of my office floor are slanted downwards with some sections (mostly the corners of the room) more slanted than others.  When I sit at my desk I am leaning enough to cause next / back pain.  If I sit in the corner of the room I swear it feels like I am about to fall out of the chair. Pens roll off my desk, but you wouldn't see the floor sinking just by looking at it.

Assuming no structural or safety issues with the office, what can I do to compensate for this so that I feel like I am sitting on a flat surface?

I am picking up a large floor mat today to see if placing a few sheets of large paper under the part of the mat covering the slanted portion of the floor will raise me up slightly.

Comment: There has to be one flat spot the size of a chair.

Comment: I know that there WILL be one flat spot there If he rotates the chair. but In office I assume there won't be space to rotate the table to suit the chair

Answer (score 5):

When I was renting my old house I wanted to use one of the guest bedrooms as an office. I didn't want to use one of those plastic mats for my office chair and the floor was a bit unlevel at the wall so my desk was going to be tilted backward.

Since I was renting the house I couldn't tear out the carpet or get the floor fixed, so I decided to build a platform just big enough for my desk and chair to sit on. If you are ok with a bit of DIY construction work, I would suggest building something similar.

I used 4 sheets of 1/2" plywood to build a 1-inch tall base by placing two sheets side by side and then placing the second two sheets perpendicularly on top of the first two. This gave me an 8ftx8ft square platform. I secured the sheets of plywood together with 3/4 inch screws placed every 0.5-ft in a square pattern across the platform. Once I finished building it, I used some shims to level the platform. Then to make it presentable I applied wood grain peel and press floor tiles to the top of the platform and around the edges.

In total, I only spent around $100 for all of the materials and was able to put it together in an afternoon.  It solved both the carpet and the unlevel floor problem simultaneously and actually looked really good. When I moved out of the house It was pretty easy to dismantle since it was just screwed together.

Answer (score 1):

It might look silly, but health and comfort are paramount so who cares. Use a balance chair, perhaps the kind that use a balloon ball for posture.

Alternatively, if you need back support you could try a large bean bag. You can put a pedestal underneath to adjust it to a comfortable height.

In either case a gravitational balance can be achieved just by shifting your position in the chair.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in office I am assuming you would have trash of papers. All you have to do is to fold a paper 7 times(you can't fold more than that) and place it below the chair/table leg. If It is still too short then you can go for stack of 2 or 3 such folded paper.